# Title case for "The"

Tags: capitalization, definite-articles, titles, headline-case

If I'm writing a sentence with a media title (book, TV show, movie, etc.), how do I present the word "the"? For example, would I write, "I was watching The Mandalorian," or "I was watching the Mandalorian"?

Comment: The answers to the other question say that you should capitalize it if it's the first word in the title (which it is in this case).

Comment: Titles should be set in italic.